# How to forcefully exit VBA code having loops using Form_Timer Event

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an MS Access code with *Do While* loops for IE navigation for data fetching. There is no issue in navigation, but navigation code goes in sleep mode(ie no url navigation) after some time.

So now I want to use the Form_timer event to restart the VBA code after 5 minutes. I am using below mentioned code, but after the first run, Form_Timer code is not running properly because the main VBA code is in sleep mode.

Suggestion required regarding my code so I will be able to stop the running code and then restart it as per the timer value.

```
Sub Form_Timer()

    getdata       

End Sub
```

Comment: `Exit Sub` will exit the current `Sub Form_Timer()`, nothing else. This cannot work as you want.

Comment: yes it is doing same,If possible if there is any option so that i will be able to stop getdata code...thanks.

Comment: If you intend to bail out of the timer loop and don't want it to ever repeat, then add "Me.TimerInterval = 0" just before you exit sub. ANd yes, Andre is correct that your 'getdata' and iminutes = 0 will never be executed because you get out before they can execute.

Comment: There is no issue in timer loop,issue in getdata loop as after some navigation not responding.So i want to stop get data and then restart using timer value

Comment: COuld you post your getdata code so we have a clear picture ? I don't understand what your "sleep mode" is about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i resolve my issue after changing code and adding ie.state check in if condition of Do Loop,after this change now timer is working peroperly.I use below mentioned for above issue resolution.

```
if ie.readystate=ReadyState_Uninitilized or rowcount>maxid then exit do
```

Comment: You still have not addressed the code you posted above. The ONLY thing that code will do is set iMinutes to 1 each time it enters. It will NEVER reset iMinutes, nor will it ever execute 'getdata'. iMinutes needs to be a 'Form-level' variable else it will always be zero when entering. Set the Form Timer to 1000, add a Debug.Print iMinutes after you add 1 to it, and put a MSGBOX in place of 'getdate'. Will always show 1 for iTimer and you will never get the message.

Comment: Now i edit my code,i use only time_interval=1000 and use above code to resolve my issue.